# AWS CDK v2 Invoke Lambda from Codepipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I need to invoke a Lambda function from AWS CDK v2.

The Lambda function invalidates a Cloudfront Distribution.  The Lambda function is completed and works fine.  I just need to know how to call this function from the codepipeline via CDK after my deploy step.

I have seen examples using v1 but not in v2.

Can anybody help ?   Ideally an example in .net

EDIT : Further information - I am working in a multi account environment where we have a Dev Ops account and the Cloudfront, S3 Bucket and Lambda function live in another account.

Thanks

Comment: Are you referring to CDK pipelines (the `pipelines` module)? If so, add a CodeBuildStep and invoke the lambda with the CLI.

Comment: @gshpychka I just updated the question to include an extra detail.  I am working in a multi account environment so the I can't simply use the CLI as the Dev Ops AWS Account does not have access to the Lambda function from the CLI.  I presume so anyway ? 

My first idea was to invalidate the Cloudfront distribution from the CLI but same issue.

Comment: The CLI call will be in a CodeBuild Step, which you can grant the necessary permission to.